# How to Send sms to customer mobile if order is placed via Magento admin panel

Tags: php, sms, magento-1.8

I have already done sms integration for the orders placed by customer using my website. But I want to send sms to customer mobile number when order is placed by admin (site owner) using magento admin panel. In magento admin has the option to place order for the customer using the admin panel.

Comment: ,Have you found a way how to do this without plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this magento API authentication code details here for orders and customers

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-CreateasimpleproductasanAdminuserwithOAuthauthentication

you will be able to see how to obtain the customer information and order information from the API

OR

you can check out this plugins http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sms-notifier.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-notification-sms-text-message.html

You will have to enter the users phone number and than with the help of the plugins you can send the sms notification.

Comment: hi ankita thanks for your response, i am not used plugin,  i was already implement sms with custom code gave by sms api provider, so with that same code only i need to send sms.

Comment: Ok so you have done sms gateway integration on your site manually.

Comment: yes, i want code for getting customer mobile number and order id, once the admin place the order via admin panel.. i already have code getting above information if the order placed by customer using website..